# Send SMS from Flutter app without user interaction?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sms

I have a fixed phone number and I want to send a text SMS on that number from my flutter app.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained

code snippet

```
    SmsSender sender = SmsSender();
    String address = "1234567";

    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage(address, 'Hello flutter!');
    message.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
        print("SMS is sent!");
        setState(() {
          _message = "SMS is sent";
        });
      } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
        print("SMS is delivered!");
        setState(() {
          _message = "SMS is delivered!";
        });
      }
    });
    sender.sendSms(message);
```

working demo

[image]

output

```
D/flutter_sms(31553): Sent result: Activity.RESULT_OK
I/flutter (31553): SMS is sent!
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    SmsSender sender = SmsSender();
    String address = "1234567";

    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage(address, 'Hello flutter!');
    message.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
      if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
        print("SMS is sent!");
      } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
        print("SMS is delivered!");
      }
    });
    sender.sendSms(message);

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It working in android....but how could we achieve this in IOS?

Comment: Can you suggest that will work on both iOS and Android ?

Comment: flutter packages get
Resolving dependencies... 
Error on line 33, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
   ╷
33 │   sms: ^0.2.0